# Calling a JavaScript function in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this function in another thread to return the width of a webpage:

```
<script>
    function getWindowSize(){
        var d= document, root= d.documentElement, body= d.body;
        var wid= window.innerWidth || root.clientWidth || body.clientWidth, 
        return [hi]
    }
</script>
```

I'd like the text on my screen to scale based on the width of the page.  There may be a better way of doing this, but this is what I thought of.  If there is a better way, I'd definitely like to know.  Anyway, let's go on:

```
<p class="purple center" style="font-size: 'getWindowSize()/10'px;">Navigation</p>
```

What I'm trying to do here is run the JS method to get the width, divide by 10, then size the word 'Navigation' accordingly.

Comment: No, but you can use the `vw` unit.  Generally you would just set up breakpoints to set the best size for a range of widths.

Comment: just access the `p` in js and change it's `style.fontSize` dynamically

Comment: @Ramanlfc How does one go about doing that?

Comment: @TfarcrawIIV https://davidwalsh.name/change-text-size-onclick-with-javascript

Comment: `.purple {
  font-size: 10vw;
  }`. You don't need, and you also don't *want*, Javascript for this trivial task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adjusts automatically as soon as the browser window is being resized, and uses only css:

```css
.purple {
  font-size: 10vw;
  }
```

```html
<p class="purple center">Navigation</p>
```

As commented by igarciaoliver:

> `vw` and `vh` are units based on the width and height of the viewport.
>   `1vw` = relative to 1% of the width of the viewport - `1vh` = Relative
>   to 1% of the height of the viewport.

Comment: for clarification: vw and vh are units based on the width and height of the window. vw = Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport - vh = Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport

Comment: That is worth adding to the answer, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to call JS from CSS. CSS is for the styling. You can access the CSS elements from JS and change aspects of them dynamically though.

Check out this example for how to change css with JS:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Also if you want to use jQuery there are some ways to change the css too: 
http://api.jquery.com/css/
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

CSS can not call JS functions.

CSS in JS can be dynamically styled.

try this code,

HTML

```
<p id="sizing">hi</p>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
    (function getWindowSize() {
        var el  = document.getElementById('sizing');

        var d   = document, root= d.documentElement, body= d.body;
        var wid = window.innerWidth || root.clientWidth || body.clientWidth;

        return el.style.fontSize = (wid/12)+"px";
    })();
};
```

good day~